# Tick and label alignment for Highcharts datetime

Tags: javascript, datetime, highcharts

I have a chart with multiple samples but all at the same time. How do I get Highcharts to put a tick and corresponding label on each value? I've tried explicitly setting the `tickPoints` with the datetimes but it doesn't work.

[Invalid tick alignment example](http://jsfiddle.net/timburgess/37kkb6j2/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Worked this out. Essentially, I implemented a custom `tickPositioner` function that puts ticks (if enabled) and their respective labels on each value.

```
xAxis: {
  tickPositioner: function() {
    var ticks = [1496275200000, 1496880000000, 1497484800000, 1499299200000];
    // this line makes highcharts aware the values are dates
    ticks.info = this.tickPositions.info;
    return ticks;
  }
}
```

You would of course make the tick array values match your data..

An [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/timburgess/37kkb6j2/6/)